# How cant I use Doctrine + convert_tz()

Tags: php, mysql, function, doctrine

I'm trying to use convert_tz for order by my query. When I run it on mysql it works perfect but when I use it with the ORM of my application It does not work. There's a right way to write it on my code?
Here is my actual code:

```
$qb->select('table1');
$qb->from('Entities\Table1', 'table1');
$qb->orderBy("CONVERT_TZ(concat(table1.date, ' ', table1.hour), table1.timezone, 'America/Sao_Paulo')", "asc");
$qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a MySQL-specific function which isn't defined in [DQL](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-functions).

If you must use it then you'll have to use [native queries](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/native-sql.html) or install something like the [DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) library, which claims to add support for `CONVERT_TZ()`.

Comment: thanks for answer! Well, I just installed the doctrine extensions but I can't realize how can I use it together with my query. Can you show me some example?

Comment: If it's properly installed then you should be able to use `CONVERT_TZ()` as you're already doing.